# Grouping Excel Values with certain criteria

Tags: excel, time, pivot-table, average

I have these data, it's rainfall readings from a gauge. We want to calculate the amount of storms, which is defined as a rain pulse from another separated by more than 1 hour.

Basically, in the data example, anything that is yellow is one storm, the orange is a new storm, then the next yellow is another storm.

Any idea how to do this in excel?

Thanks!

[image: Data Example]

Comment: So you just want to get the total number of storms?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this will work.

=COUNTIF(B2:B13,">="&"1:00:00")

You may need to change the last part ("1:00:00") depending upon what data type you have assigned to the "Time D..." column. Alternatively, change the display of this column to be whole minutes (e.g. 15, 30, 90, 930, etc.) then the criteria changes to ">="&60.